# LD_PRELOAD open and Segmentation fault

Tags: c, bash, segmentation-fault, system-calls, ld-preload

I want to monitor the files which are opened by bash,

```
int open(const char *filename, int flags) {
    printf("Path is  %s\n", filename)
    static int (*origin_open)(const char *filename, int flags);
    if (!origin_open) {
        origin_open = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
    }
    return origin_open(filename, flags);
}
```

and compiled this shared library,

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o hookopen.so hookeopen.c -ldl
```

then ran the following command,

```
LD_PRELOAD="./hookeopen.so" /bin/bash
```

Finally got the error,

```
Path is: '/dev/tty'
Segmentation fault
```

How can I solve the error? Thanks.

Comment: And *where* does the segmentation fault occur?  Note that [the correct declaration for `open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is `open( const char *filename, int flags, ... )`.  You can hack it by using `open( const char *filename, int flags, mode_t mode );`, but then you'll have problems if you `#include` the proper headers.

Comment: First if all you should test `dlsym` return value `!= NULL`....

Comment: @LPs That too...